# Can GROUP BY query have non aggregate function call in projection list?

Tags: sql

Is the following SQL query valid?

```
SELECT SOME_NON_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(col1), SUM(col2)
FROM Table
GROUP BY col1, col2;
```

Or does it need to be:

```
SELECT FF, SUM(col2)
FROM Table
GROUP BY col1, SOME_NON_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(col1) as FF;
```

Comment: Do you really mean `GROUP BY col2` and at the same time `SUM(col2)`? That doesn't make much sense as `SUM(col2) = col2`. You should probably replace it by `SUM(col3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query 1 is valid ANSI SQL, but both `SUM(col2)` and `GROUP BY col2` at the same time makes no sense. Either `GROUP BY` **or** aggregate function argument is the main rule!

Query 2 is invalid ANSI SQL syntax. The `GROUP BY` can only contain columns (some dbms allow general expressions too, but not in ANSI SQL.) You can not specify column aliases in the GROUP BY either.

**Edit:**

I suppose you want:

```
SELECT SOME_NON_AGGREGATE_FUNCTION(col1), SUM(col2)
FROM Table
GROUP BY col1;
```

I.e. `GROUP BY col1` only, since col2 is used as argument to a aggregate function!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question / your answer carefully enough. I undid the downvote. The reason for it was `both SUM(col2) and GROUP BY col2` as I overlooked that it is col2 in both cases. It does make sense to have non-aggregate functions and aggregate functions at the same time, but obviously not like this.